# Install NFS server

Tags: apt, nfs

On my Raspberry I try to install NFS like following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

The last command returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nfs-common : Depends: libtirpc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: rpcbind but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong?" Probably trying to run Wheezy which is no longer supported by the Foundation.

Comment: @Milliways Ah, thank you! Please, post it as an answer. There may be some other people like me, who still leaving in 2015 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest raspbian is based on *jessie*, so you should change your source to jessie.

So just change

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

to

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```